# How to fix WAMP page access when using IP Address instead of localhost in the URL

Tags: php, mysql, windows, apache, wamp

I have recently built my local test server WAMP by using Windows 7 Pro 64bit OS.  I have also chosen to use the 32bit programs (Apache, MySQL & PHP) so my WAMP spec would be x86 V11 binary Thread Safe (TS).  I want to keep all development related items into the C:\dev folder or directory, so my file system looks like this:

```
C:\dev\bin\apache24\
C:\dev\bin\MySQL5.6\
C:\dev\bin\PHP5.6\
C:\dev\www\phpMysqlAdmin
C:\dev\www\HollyGhost.com\login.php
```

Settings: my.ini

```
# Path to the installation directory.
basedir = "C:/dev/bin/MySQL5.6/"

# Path to the database data directory
 datadir = "C:/dev/bin/MySQL5.6/data/"

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port = 3306

# Server Id.
server_id = 1

C:\Winows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

If I need to view the web site: `http://localhost/HollyGhost.com/login.php` the site comes up without any issues and works great; but if I rewrite the URL on the same box to: `http://127.0.0.1/HollyGhost.com/login.php` the site renders the login page but I cannot log into the system.  All I am getting when I attempt to log in is the login page keeps refreshing.  I tried to do the same from another PC and I am getting the same result.  I need to do this so I can test other devices locally.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I am not sure if this issue is a permission problem based on the fact that MySQL data is stored in the `\MySQl5.6\data` directory. If so, how do I go about fixing it.

Comment: If it's a test environment, what does it matter if you access via localhost namespace or loopback IP?  Does your page load at all by ip?

Comment: When I use the loopback IP the login page shows up, but as I say I just can't get by the login in page.  I need to test other devices locally as well.

Comment: Is mySQL restricting to "localhost" connections vs 127.0.0.1?  Could be a disconnect there.

Comment: I am not sure of going about it to figure that out.  Where should I look?

Comment: It would be somewhere in the WAMP/XAMPP configurations, or possibly on the database/table security within mysql.  Sorry, it's tough for me to say specifically without poking around in your system.

Comment: @AndrewCoder the connection to the mysql is made from the server, not from the client. So, unless the TO uses the hostname entered by the user to connect to the mysql server, the connection should be indifferent whether the user used IP or hostname to reach the website.

Comment: This is true.  Not sure though if he is specifying localhost vs 127.0.0.1 in his script for his sql connection.

Comment: in the sql connection I am using: host='localhost';

Comment: Are you using WordPress??

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the Windows Firewall -> Advance setting -> Inbound Rules.  The Inbound Rules for MySQL Profile was set to Private and the Program was set to Any.  I change Profile to "Domain, Private" and set Program to point to MySQL installation directory "MySQL.exe" this works for me after rebooting all network devices and PCs.